# MongoDB aggregate: count of elements in an object key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB document like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5ff09030cd55d6d9f378d460"
    },
    "username": "a value",
    "userid": "123456",
    "last_access_ts": 1612426253,
    "last_access": "2021-2-4 9:10:53",
    "anotherid": 12345678910,
    "verified_date": "2021-1-2 16:24:32",
    "verified_ts": 1609601072,
    "group_users": {
      "-1001159747589": [
        {
          "anotherid": 12345678910,
          "userid": "123456"
        }
      ],
      "-1001143137644": [
        {
          "anotherid": 12345678910,
          "userid": "123456"
        }
      ],
      "-1001368608972": [
        {
          "anotherid": 12345678910,
          "userid": "123456"
        }
      ]
    },
    "registered_access": "2021-1-2 16:24:42",
  }
]
```

I've two questions.

First one: I need to count the elements inside each `group_users[key]` object, and I'm stuck with this aggregate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      username: "a value"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      userid: 1,
      "groups": {
        "$objectToArray": "$group_users"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$groups",
  },
])
```

This aggregate gives me this result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ff09030cd55d6d9f378d460"),
    "groups": {
      "k": "-1001449720492",
      "v": [
        {
          "anotherid": 12345678910,
          "userid": "123456"
        }
      ]
    },
    "userid": "123456"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ff09030cd55d6d9f378d460"),
    "groups": {
      "k": "-1001159747589",
      "v": [
        {
          "anotherid": 12345678910,
          "userid": "123456"
        }
      ]
    },
    "userid": "123456"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ff09030cd55d6d9f378d460"),
    "groups": {
      "k": "-1001143137644",
      "v": [
        {
          "anotherid": 12345678910,
          "userid": "123456"
        }
      ]
    },
    "userid": "123456"
  }
]
```

How can I count each single `groups[v]` and then re-group the data? I would like to have a result like:

```
{
    ... some user data
    "groups": {
        "group_key": "count",
        "second_group_key": "count",
        "third_group_key": "count"
    }

}
```

Is it possible with aggregate or I need to loop in the code?

My second question is always about the `group_users`. Is possible to have, recursively, the user data inside a `group_users` object?

I mean, every object inside `group_users` is an array of users; from this array can I have the user data (maybe with `$graphLookup`?) using the `userid` field or the `anotherid` field?

As a result from this second aggregate I would like to have something like this:

```
{
    ... some user data
    "groups": {
        "group_key": [{"userid": userid, "username": username}],
        "second_group_key": [{"userid": userid, "username": username}],
        "third_group_key": [{"userid": userid, "username": username}]
    }
}
```

Obviously I can limit this "recursion" to 10 elements per time.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$objectToArray` convert `group_users` object to array
- `$let` to Bind variable `group_arr` for use in the specified expression, and returns the result of the expression.
- `$map` to iterate loop of bind variable `group_arr`, get size of total element of v and return k and v,
- `$arrayToObject` convert returned array from `$map` to object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { username: "a value" } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      userid: 1,
      groups: {
        $let: {
          vars: { group_arr: { $objectToArray: "$group_users" } },
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: "$$group_arr",
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.k",
                  v: { $size: "$$this.v" }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q3l-CwSoOEH)

---

Second question,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `groups` array
- `$lookup` with pipeline, match `anotherid` `$in` condition and return required fields
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `groups` array
- `$arrayToObject` convert `groups` array to object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { username: "a value" } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      userid: 1,
      groups: { $objectToArray: "$group_users" }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$groups" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: { anotherid: "$groups.v.anotherid" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$anotherid", "$$anotherid"] } } },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            userid: 1,
            username: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "groups.v"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      groups: { $push: "$groups" },
      userid: { $first: "$userid" }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { groups: { $arrayToObject: "$groups" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-gMqcLNWYSx)

Comment: Thank you! They work like a charm. Just a last question: how about complexity? Could they be slow in case I have a lot of data?

Comment: yes it would me slow because of lots of conversation, i would suggest to improve your schema and structure as per your actual project requirement. this kind of operations may cause performance issues. you can see which stage takes more process time using [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html)

Comment: okay, thank you. A last last question: about the second one aggregate, if I limit to 10 users per time (the conversion) the request for a single group (not third like in the example), would this be the same slow?

Comment: it depends on elements in array, you will get better idea using explain() function.